# Activity monitor - Memory usage when profiling / not profiling

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, instruments

Any idea why my app's memory usage does *not* increase whilst using Instruments profiler (searching for leaks), but does when I don't use any profiler? To the tune of 1MB per operation performed. Instruments does not show any leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OS memory management is a complex thing. It is likely that when you free memory it is not returned immediately to the system, but instead it is still "attached" to your process to make any future allocations your application needs more efficient. Although it is recorded as part of your process's memory space, it would be marked as unused, and when the system is running out of memory (or when your application exits), it would then reclaim the unused memory from your application.

If Instruments isn't reporting any leaks, you should be fine.